# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 tomcat properties not updated

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm dabbling with IntelliJ after working with eclipse for many years. I've setup my tomcat server and I have my application running just fine. I updated a properties file on my file system in my tomcat conf folder, but the new file contents are not showing up. When debugging in IntelliJ, i see that it has the contents of my old properties file. How can I update intelliJ so it see's my new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ creates a small copy of tomcat to start the application server as eclipse does, depending of the operating system you can find it in:

```
Windows: C:\Users\${user}\.IntelliJIdea${version}\system\tomcat\
Linux  : /home/${user}/.IntelliJIdea${version}/system/tomcat/
Mac    : /Users/${user}/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea${version}/tomcat/
```

So you should update the configuration file in the respective directory

Comment: Sounds good i will check that when I get to work. Any way to clean this through IntelliJ itself?

Comment: I deleted my server from the IntelliJIdea cache and when I rerun my app, the generated cache has the new properties file that I had put in my actual server directory, but when I debug through the app, it's still using the old properties file. I can't figure out where it's getting this from.

Comment: I'm a moron. I was copying my new properties file to tomcat's conf folder instead of the lib folder... 